# How to config user_prefs (SpamAssassin) individually per user in Redis DB?

Tags: freebsd, spamassassin, redis, amavis

I'm going to implement mail gateway with FreeBSD 10.1.
So, I installed Postfix, Amavisd, Clamav, Spamassassin, Procmail (for filtering spam from maildir to spam folder), Bayes with Redis database. I have config them to work together. It can work well as root user.

My point is how to config user_prefs individually per user, so that Spamassassin can learn based on different users. (e.g. different whitelist). And also storing those user preferences in Redis database.

p.s. So far, I haven't  found a tutorial on Redis other than official documentation (which doesn't help so much). And I'm not clear on sa-learn per user very well. I really appreciate good tutorial of explanation in this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around so many things and I finally found that RedisDB isn't quite suitable like this. Even though RedisDB is fast, this scenario is best fit with relational database.

There are a few of alternative ways. So I go with traditional MySQL.
I found great tutorial for FreeBSD here http://www.purplehat.org/?page_id=4 . This link is very helpful in introducing my to Maia Mailguard. Despite the fact that I need to use Amavisd-new, I followed the explicit steps in that link. It can be applied to Amavisd-new well because Maia Mailguard was once a part of Amavisd package. Its configuration goes in similar way.

By the way, thank you for interesting and upvoting this question.